# python code for replacing character and remove header

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying code to remove the header from multiple CSV files and add | delimiter by replacing, here is my code but it's getting out-

```
import time, os
from datetime import datetime
def remove_header_replace_delimiter():
    src_folder = 'path'
    src_files = os.listdir(src_folder)
    print(src_files)
    for file_name in src_files:
        with open('path' + file_name, 'r') as inp, open('path' + file_name, 'w') as out:
            next(inp)
            for line in inp:
                line = line.replace(',', '|')
                print(line)
                out.write(line)
```

Myfile content -

```
Date,Runner Name,Automation,Order Number,SON,Account Name,Quote Number,Product Code,Status
01/02/2021 10:43:25,dsadsa,AS Silver,444,3323,aaapp,W-3342,AQS-11-L,Failed
01/02/2021 10:57:52,dsfsdds,AS Silver,34333,3213,defsd,A-1222,fdsfds-L,Success
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "/" between `path` and `file_name` causing it to try and open a file called "pathMyfile.txt" when `src_folder="path"` and your file is called "Myfile.txt"
Also you might want to use `src_folder` instead of hardcoding "path" in your file open line.
Lastly, you could try to use f-strings instead of string concatenation with `+` for clarity and performance.

Example:

```
import time, os
from datetime import datetime
def remove_header_replace_delimiter():
    src_folder = 'path'
    src_files = os.listdir(src_folder)
    print(src_files)
    for file_name in src_files:
        with open(f'{src_folder}/{file_name}', 'r') as inp, open(f'{src_folder}/fixed_{file_name}', 'w') as out:
            next(inp)
            for line in inp:
                line = line.replace(',', '|')
                print(line)
                out.write(line)

remove_header_replace_delimiter()
```

Comment: Because you can't read and write the same file at the same time. You are writing in between reading lines. Updated code should work.